# What's the correct way to create an endpoint in a API REST

Tags: api, rest, endpoint, restful-url

I'm drawing my API routes.

A user has projects, projects have actors, actors have addresses.

There is no address without an actor, there is no actor without a project, and there is no project without a user.

Would this be the correct way to build the end_point?

GET /users/{user_id}/projects/{project_id}/actors/{actor_id}/addresses

Comment: sorry.. i updated...

Answer (score 0):

> There is no such thing as a REST endpoint. There are resources. -- [Fielding, 2018](https://twitter.com/fielding/status/1052976631374000128)

What you seem to be asking about here is how to design the identifier for your [resource](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1).

REST doesn't care what spelling conventions you use for your resource identifiers, so long as they satisfy the production rules described by [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A).

Identifiers that load data into the query part are convenient if you are expecting to leverage HTML forms:

```
GET /addresses?user={user_id}&project={project_id}&actor=actor_id
```

But that design is not particularly convenient if you are expecting to use dot segments to reference other resources.

Choosing some alternative that is described by a [URI Template](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6570) will make some things easier down the road.

```
/users/{user_id}/projects/{project_id}/actors/{actor_id}/addresses
```

That's *fine*.  Other spellings would also be *fine* (hint: URL shorteners *work*).

Broadly, you choose identifier spellings by thinking about the different contexts in which a human being has to look at the URI (documentation for your API, browser histories, access logs, etc.) and choose a spelling that works well in at least one of those settings.